# Laravel Validation of Checkbox and Input?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel, how do I do validation to check if checkbox is checked and text input is not empty.

For example:

If checkbox is ticked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="has_login" checked="checked" value="1">
```

and pin is not empty then validation should be passed.

```
<input type="text" name="pin" value="">
```

In Request file file:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
          'has_login' => ??,
    ];
}
```

Comment: what's your checkbox name?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules First one is "accepted" and you can combine it with `"pin" => "required"`

Comment: @apokryfos How to combine with `"pin" => "required"`

Comment: You should really read the documentation. All the information is there.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
          'has_login' => 'accepted',
          'pin' => 'required',
    ];
}
```